# PhoneGap: setContentView is undefined for the type new Runnable

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to create a PhoneGap plugin tp play video using VideoView. But I'm getting the following error:

setContentView is undefined for the type new Runnable.

```
package com.phonegap.plugins.video;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayer extends CordovaPlugin {

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if ("playVideo".equals(action)) {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                setContentView(videoHolder);
                videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Android/data/Bis/v2.mp4"));
                videoHolder.requestFocus();
                videoHolder.start();            
                callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any change in the way SetContentView needs to be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cordova.getActivity().setContentView()`. Since inside the `Runnable` the this refers to the inner class `Runnable`

Comment: The method setContentView() is undefined for the type VideoPlayer